# WordPress Woocommerce Blocks, edit core components

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gutenberg-blocks

Earlier this year I was using [woo-gutenberg-products-blocks](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gutenberg-products-block) to integrate Woocommerce products to Gutenberg editor in WordPress. Now the Gutenberg blocks in integrated with the core Woocommerce. 
My question : **How can I modify the core components?** 
For example: use my own API to fetch products data, change CSS and text.

Answer (score 1):

So after searching, it appears that in order to change the core plugin, i needed to download the source code from their GitHub repository, follow the instructions for developments and then activate it as a separate plugin.